# Is there any chance that Stack Overflow might split into several smaller sites?

Tags: discussion

So I have noticed that Stack Overflow gets a lot of traffic, like a question is asked every 20 seconds or so. This can mean that if a question isn't answered within a few minutes it can end up getting lost unanswered. How likely is it that Stack Overflow may split into several more manageable sites for different programming languages? Has it been confirmed that it will/won't happen? I feel that it could help valuable questions that may be tough to answer to be found.

Comment: What makes you feel stack overflow may split instead of the huge community efforts to keep it converged achieving it's vision?

Comment: I feel that some questions just end up off the page before they are noticed.

Comment: This isnt a request I an just wondering how likley it is to happen.

Comment: It isn't. Don't use the front page, follow the tags you like, and filter by unanswered if you're not tracking live instead.

Comment: There are communities that have been added to the stack exchange network that do overlap with [main] in places but I suspect you mean for a specific language, which is unlikely to happen as any questions would likely be on topic for [main] too.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "split into smaller sites". Do you mean split by language, as assumed by some comments and answers, or do you mean by some other dimension, such as question difficulty?

Comment: i was wondering if there was any chance it would be split by language

Comment: Splitting by language is highly impractical. Take web technologies for example that encompass numerous cross over languages

Comment: @charlietfl the examples are endless. There's also systems like Android where lots of Java answers apply, but not all Android questions apply to Java. Then there's the fun matter of several languages with a shared SDK, such as Java, Kotlin, Scala, Groovy, and several others. Not to forget when said languages are cross-platform and affect several techs, and have different ways to compile (JVM Kotlin, Kotlin JS, and Kotlin Native, all of which are Kotlin, but with vastly different underlying stdlibs aside the Kotlin stdlib)

Comment: The ways technologies overlap could create a list that fills several books, and all of them are reasons why splitting up by tech or language is a fundamentally bad idea. There's so many things that are heavily intertwined in some ways, but vastly different in others, that make a site per language or tech an extremely unsustainable way to structure a Q&A network

Comment: Well, I would support a dedicated Regex sub-site, so we don't have those questions here anymore.

Comment: @Tom Regex doesn't count, and outsourcing regex would mean substantially less delete wars, close wars, and other wars and lack of closing and too much closing, depending on who you ask, for the rest of us. Unlike the rest of tech, a regex sub-site only has advantages :')

Comment: Extending from what Tom commented, I would personally not be apposed to splitting programming-but-not-actually-programming questions from Stack Overflow. HTML, CSS, SQL, regex, docker-compose... they're topics generally guarded by a community mindset which is not very compatible with Stack Overflow in general; I.E. the norm is to just answer everything rather than to dupe-close. Something I fully understand because the devil is usually in the tiniest variations when it comes to such questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *"How likely is it that Stack Overflow may split into several more manageable sites for different programming languages?"*

## 0% Chance

There's no point in splitting Stack Overflow into different sites per language, as you can filter questions by tag, for example: [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Nobody is an expert on *every* language. People answering questions usually keep an eye on one or more specific tags.

Comment: And even people who are experts at several languages tend to have preferences or other systems on what they want to answer today. Expecting to keep up with every single question on several areas of expertise is more or less an exercise in being way in over your head due to volume alone.